# can somebody explain to me, why a transposed image divide by 9 gray scale image

Tags: numpy, opencv

I don't understand why do it happens

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwHIE.png)

```
src = cv2.imread('./baboon.jpg')
color1 = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
dst = np.transpose(color1)
color2 = dst.reshape(512,512,3)
images = [color1, color2]
title = ['original', 'transposed']

for i in range(2):
plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
plt.imshow(images[i])
plt.title(title[i])
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the result of transposing a 3-channel matrix? In the end it is all about what is in the raw memory before you reshape the matrix.

Comment: I think you have to specify the axes. From the docs: "For an n-D array, if axes are given, their order indicates how the axes are permuted (see Examples). If axes are not provided, then transpose(a).shape == a.shape[::-1]."

Comment: `np.transpose(color1, (1,0,2))` makes more sense.  Leave color axis 3, last.

Comment: Look at the shape of `dst`.  It has the size 3 dimension first.  It hasn't just "rotated" the image, it has altered how it's represented.  The following `reshape` doesn't "move" that color channel to the end.  It jumbles the data.  Experiment with something smaller, like a `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)`.  Transpose, and then reshape back to (3,4). What happens to the number layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src = cv2.imread('./baboon.jpg')
color1 = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
dst = np.transpose(color1, (1,0,2))
color2 = dst.reshape(512,512,3)
images = [color1, color2]
title = ['original', 'transposed']

for i in range(2):
    plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images[i])
    plt.title(title[i])
    plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```